# Hare induction problem

Tags: induction

Jovian hares are hermaphrodite. Each mature Jovian hare produces one
leveret during each breeding cycle. Each leveret takes two breeding cycles to mature into a fully-grown hare, and then lives for ever. Starting with a single newly-born Jovian leveret,how many hares (including leverets) are there after 47 breeding cycles?

This is the question that I am being asked to consider. I have found the equation to calculate the number of hares and leverets after $n$ breeding cycles. It is $M_n = M_{n-1}+M_{n-3}$ and have found the number of hares and leverets that will present after 47 breeding cycles. I am just a little iffy on how to write a proof of the recurrence relation. Can someone enlighten me on how to do this for this problem?

Answer (score 1):

How many hares are there after $n$ cycles?

- All the hares that were alive last cycle, because they live forever.  This is $M_{n-1}$ hares.
- One leveret for each fully-grown hare; that is, one for each hare that is at least three cycles old.  This is $M_{n-3}$ hares.